# React getDerivedStateFromProps - setSate

Tags: reactjs

If you are using the `getDerivedStateFromProps` function, how do you set the state?

For example, I have the following:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.data.imo && nextProps.data.imo !== prevState.imo) {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/get/latestcalls/' + nextProps.data.imo)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log('got data: ',data);
                prevState.latestcalls = data;
                return ({latestcalls: data})
            })
            .catch('Error: ', console.log)
    }
    return null;
}
```

and

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.latestcalls);
    return (...
```

In the `render` function, the `this.state.latestcalls`, is always behind, i.e. the `prevSate`.

Question

In the `getDerivedStateFromProps` function I get the data, and need to set the current state. Is this possible?

Because it is `static`, I am cannot call `this.setState...`.

Thanks

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` for `React.Component` or `useEffect` for `React.FC`. [getDerivedStateFromProps doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) You can find

> If you need to **perform a side effect** (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle instead.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      latestcalls: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { data: { imo } } = this.props;
    if (imo) {
      this.fetchData();
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { data: { imo: prevImo } } = prevProps;
    const { data: { imo: nextImo } } = this.props;
    if (prevImo !== nextImo) {
      this.fetchData();
    }
  }

  fetchData() {
    const { data: { imo } } = this.props;

    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/get/latestcalls/${imo}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ latestcalls: data, });
      })
      .catch('Error: ', console.log);
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

for React.FC

```
const MyComponent = ({ data: { imo } }) => {
  const [latestcalls, setLatestcalls] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (imo) {
      fetch(`http://localhost:3001/get/latestcalls/${imo}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setLatestcalls(data);
      })
      .catch('Error: ', console.log);
    }
  }, [imo]);

  return null;
}
```

Comment: @KrillSkomarovskiy, thank you. This looks like it is working. However, I get an error:  `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` because `tthis.prevProps: undefined`., on the following line: `const { data: { imo: prevImo } } = this.prevProps;`.

Comment: My mistake. Rename this.prevProps to prevProps

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is for quite rare need to re-generate `state` after `props` are changed. It was not intended to implement async logic like you show. That's why it's `static`: it's just a sync pure function.

`componentDidUpdate` is natural place to do that.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.data.imo && this.props.data.imo !== prevState.imo) {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/get/latestcalls/' + nextProps.data.imo)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((latestcalls) => {
                this.setState({latestcalls})
            })
            .catch('Error: ', console.log)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's about right! Additional suggested documentation to read: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: @skyboyer, thank you for your reply, but I don't think this will work for my situation, because the `componentDidUpdate` function is called multiple times. I only want to perform the data call once.

Comment: @Richard, so add check for `prevState.latestcalls` into `if`. By the way, `getDerivedStateFromProps` also is called for multiple times, each time any prop or state is changed.